# How to setup log4net to log from an interface

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-appender

I am using log4net to log events/info from my application. I have an interface `IReader` that is implemented by at least 4 classes and it can grow. Each class has a `ReadBuffer()` method where I want to log the error if the read failed. Following is the method definition for one class:

```
public class IPortM350Connection : IReader
{

    public void ReadBuffer()
    {
        try
        {
            this.AddToLog(iqBeaconLogType.Info, string.Format("Reader# {0} start reading.", SerialNumber));
            while (IsConnected)
            {
                if (IportM350Obj != null && IportM350Obj.DataStream.IsOpen)
                {
                    var data = IportM350Obj.GetBeaconTags();
                    var rampTagList = Utility.Identec350TagToTag(data);
                    if (rampTagList != null && rampTagList.Any())
                    {
                        var e = new RampTagReadEventArg(rampTagList);
                        // trigger Successful Tag read event
                        ReadMessage(this, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ReaderTimeoutException ex)
        {
            this.AddToLog(iqBeaconLogType.Fatal, string.Format("Reader# {0} failed reading.", SerialNumber));

        }

    }
}
```

The AddToLog extension method is responsible for creating the log which is shown below.

```
    public static void AddToLog(this object logObject, iqBeaconLogType logType, string message)
    {
        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(logObject.GetType());

        var msg = string.Format("Event occured in : {0} at time {1}. Event Log : {2}",
                        logObject.GetType().ToString(),DateTime.Now.ToString(), message);
        log.Fatal(msg);
    }
```

This method works fine when I setup my config file to read the class like below:

```
<logger name="iqBeaconv7_1.ReaderLayer.Connection.IPortM350Connection" additivity="False">
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileCompositeAppenderForIPort350Connection"/>
</logger>
```

However, I think that if I am able to pass IReader interface to the logger, then I can log all classes with the same file. I get no log entries when I replace `IPortM350Connection` with `IReader`. Has anyone written a config file for an interface, or got any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AddToLog` method is creating a logger whose name is the name of the derived class (`logObject.GetType()`).  You may want to use a common logger for all derived classes, whose name is either hardwired, or is the name of your interface (`IReader`).

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but you could try changing your AddToLog method to:

```
public static void AddToLog(this IReader logObject, iqBeaconLogType logType, string message)
{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(IReader));
    ...
}
```

and your log4net configuration to:

```
<logger name="iqBeaconv7_1.ReaderLayer.Connection.IReader" additivity="False">
    ...
</logger>
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your answer. I am trying to create a common logger library that can be used for any class, as is configured in the setup file. I could try passing the IReader object, but it would create a circular reference error. I ended up creating a different method to be used for the IReader interface classes only, similar to your approach and casted the object to IReader type using logObject.GetType.GetInterface('IReader').